# Loop through dictionary keys to get values based on input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

1) In my program I start with prompting a user for input.

2) I would then like to loop through the users input to get all the characters in that string, query each character individually against the dictionaries keys.

3) If a character from the input matches a key in the dictionary, I want that key's value returned.

4) This needs to be repeated for each character and the result should print those values returned in a string

To try and explain further, here is my dictionary:

```
dataDict = {
"a":"1",
"b":"2",
"c":"3",
}
```

For example:

If my input is abc, my result should be 123

If my input is cba, my result should be 321

and so on...

So far, this works if the string is only one character using the below code.
If i enter two characters, it just returns nothing.

```
dataInput=input("Enter stuff: ")

for key,value in dataDict.items():
    if dataInput == key:
    print(value)
```

How can I acheive the results i'm after?

Comment: does `dataInput` always contain all the values or `"12"` is also possible ?

Comment: `"".join(a.get(key, "") for key in w)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be looping over the dict to find the matching keys, that's *very* inefficient. A dict is designed to do fast lookups: you give it the key and it gives you the value. Eg, `dataDict["a"]` results in "1".

Also, as Tim Pietzcker mentions, doing `if dataInput == key` will only work if `dataInput` consists of a single letter, because it compares the whole `dataInput` string to `key`.

Here's a simple way to do the desired conversion. We do the lookups in a list comprehension, which creates a list of the converted values, and then we pass that list to `.join` to create a string. (I've changed the names of your variables to conform with the PEP-008 style guide).

```
data_dict = {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3",
}

data_input = "aabbccba"

s = ''.join([data_dict[c] for c in data_input])
print(s)
```

**output**

```
11223321
```

However, that's not safe: it will fail with `KeyError` if `data_input` contains a char that's not in the dictionary. Here's a better way: it adds an empty string if it gets a bad char.

```
data_input = "aaxbbcycbaz"
s = ''.join([data_dict.get(c, '') for c in data_input])
print(s)
```

**output**

```
11223321
```

Alternatively, we could convert bad data to some special value, eg 0.

```
data_input = "aaxbbcycbaz"
s = ''.join([data_dict.get(c, '0') for c in data_input])
print(s)
```

**output**

```
11022303210
```

---

Just for fun, here's a "functional" version. Guido would probably not approve of this one. :)

```
data_input = "aaxbbcycbaz"
print(''.join(filter(None, map(data_dict.get, data_input))))
11223321
```

Comment: Just for completeness, maybe show how to do it with `map()`, too?

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, ok. ;)

Comment: Not where I can test, but isn't the output from `filter` an iterable you can pass to `print`?

Comment: @tripleee Well, I guess you could do `print(*filter(None, map(data_dict.get, data_input)), sep='')`. But the OP may want the actual string.

Answer (score 1):

You should be iterating over the input string, not the dictionary. Also, you might want to use `.get()` in case the users enters a characters that's not in the dictionary:

```
for letter in dataInput:
    print(dataDict.get(letter,"X"))
```

This will print each letter on its individual line. If you want to print them in a single line, you can add the `end=""` parameter to the `print` function (and print an empty line after you're done).

The comparison you're doing would never work (in the first iteration, it would amount to `if "abc" == "a"`, I hope that makes it obvious).

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through the wrong thing. You should be iterating through the input. You don't need to iterate through the dict, because you can just look up by key.